# Help identifying the singularities of $\csc(\cos z) = \frac{1}{\sin(\cos z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am really stuck with this one:

$\frac{1}{\sin(\cos z)}$ has a singularity when $\cos z = k\pi $ since $\sin(k\pi) = 0$ but how do I solve for the value of $z$, how can i evaluate $\cos z = k\pi $?

Comment: my mistake , yes.

Comment: Do you need the poles inside a certain contour? The general case looks quit messy...

Comment: @dietervdf  for the general case i think, the question doesnt specify: given a hint i could try to do it on my own and post it back here if i happen to get stuck.

Comment: hint: $\cos z = \frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solve $\cos z = w$, let $y=e^{iz}$. Then $\cos z = \frac 12\left(y+y^{-1}\right)$. So $y+\frac{1}{y} = 2w$, or $y^2-2wy+1=0$ or $$y=\frac{2w\pm\sqrt{4w^2-4}}{2}= w \pm \sqrt{w^2-1}$$

So $iz = \log\left(k\pi\pm \sqrt{k^2\pi^2-1}\right)$.

So:

$$z = i\log\left(k\pi\pm \sqrt{k^2\pi^2-1}\right)$$

Since $(k\pi+ \sqrt{k^2\pi^2-1})(k\pi- \sqrt{k^2\pi^2-1})$=1, you actually have:

$$z=\pm i\log\left(k\pi+ \sqrt{k^2\pi^2-1}\right)$$

Now, $\log$ is a multivalued function, so for each $k$ you get infinitely many poles.

When $k=0$, the roots are $z=\frac{\pi}{2}+m\pi$ for $m\in\mathbb Z$. Those are the "real" roots.

When $k>0$, $k\pi+\sqrt{k^2\pi^2-1}$ is positive real, so $z$ is necessarily an imaginary number plus some multiply of $2\pi$.

When $k<0$, we can take any pole for $-k>0$ and add $\pi$.

So for $k>0$, the polls corresponding to $k$ and $-k$ are:

$$\pm i\ln\left(k\pi+ \sqrt{k^2\pi^2-1}\right) + m\pi$$ for some $m\in\mathbb Z$, and $\ln$ is the standard real natural log.

Comment: Ah. You beat me to it. :)

Answer (score 4):

Rough answer.

$$\cos z=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$$

So we must solve:

$$\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}=\pi k.$$

After some algebra, we get

$$e^{2iz}-2\pi ke^{iz}+1=0.$$

Let $w=e^{iz}$, the equation is now quadratic in $w$. So, by quadratic formula,

$$w=\pi k\pm\sqrt{\pi^2k^2-1}.$$

Substituting $e^{iz}$ back for w and solving for $z$ gives

$$z=-i\log\left(\pi k\pm\sqrt{\pi^2k^2-1}\right).$$

Assuming that we are using the principal branch of $\log$, you will have to add all integer multiples of $2\pi i$ to the final answer.